# Image system for franchise

Tags: web-apps, images, php, digital-asset-management

'd like to know if there's some kind of web-based software, where the franchisor can upload some kinds of material (images, banners, logos etc.) and the franchisees can edit some areas (banner texts, minor) and make some basic changes to these materials and submit to approval before downloading them.

Some kind of DAM, but I believe it's different.

Comment: No first hand experience but maybe this fits: https://marcom.com/customize-marketing-assets/

Comment: What is DAM? (Damned if I know ;-)